# How to customize the 401 in quarkus oidc?

Tags: java, openid-connect, quarkus, quarkus-oidc, quarkus-grpc

I want to customize the 401/403 status code when access token is invalid in headers. I have create an exception mapper given below :

```
import io.quarkus.security.AuthenticationFailedException;
import org.jose4j.json.internal.json_simple.JSONObject;

import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider//register as JAXRS provider
@Priority(1)
public class UnAuthorizedExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<AuthenticationFailedException> {
  @Override
  public Response toResponse(AuthenticationFailedException exception) {
   System.out.println("I m here:"+exception);
    JSONObject ob=new JSONObject();
    ob.put("errorCode",401);
    ob.put("msg","Invalid access token");
    return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
            .entity(ob.toJSONString())

      .build();
  }


}
```

But when I execute my code then above exception mapper is not executed instead following log is appearing in the console :

`io.qua.oid.run.OidcProvider`: (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) Token verification has failed: The JWT is no longer valid - claim value.

How can I customize 401/403 status code msg in quarkus oidc.

Comment: Have you tried altering the priority?